# To find the smallest integer with $n$ distinct divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example, if $n=20$, how can I find the smallest integer which has exactly $20$ distinct divisors?  Can someone give me some hints?

Comment: Do you mean $20$ *distinct* divisors?

Comment: Do you know the formula for the number of distinct positive divisors of the number $m=p_1^{a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{a_k}$ (where $p_i$ is a positive prime, $a_i\in\Bbb Z^+$)?

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Product of $a_i$'s.

Comment: No, the number is $(a_1+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(a_k+1)$. Use this formula in the answer.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Ya. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $m=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\ldots p_k^{a_k}$, we have number of divisors to be
$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots(1+a_k)$$
For this to be $20$, we want
$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots(1+a_k) = 20 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5$$
This means $m$ can have at most $3$ distinct prime divisors.

- $3$ prime divisors. The smallest possible $m$ is $2^4 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 240$.
- $2$ prime divisors. The smallest possible $m$ is of the form $2^a \cdot 3^b$. This means we need $(1+a)(1+b) = 20$, where $a\geq b$.

  - $a=9,b=1$, gives $m=2^9 \cdot 3 = 1536$.
  - $a=4,b=3$, gives $m=2^4\cdot3^3 = 432$.
- $1$ prime divisor. The smalles possible $m$ is of the form $2^{19} = 524288$.

Hence, the smallest $m$ is $240$.

Comment: So I can't generalize this to a formula? Do I have to consider all cases for all $n$?

Comment: @Galf Unfortunately, there is no nice formula. You would typically need to argue case by case.

Comment: Would taking the maximum number of divisors for $m$ always give the answer? It happened here.

Comment: Umm... I don't think my last comment is correct. I took n=24 and got 360 as the smallest. Am I correct?

Answer (score -2):

Use $2^{20} $, it has divisors $1,2,2^2, 2^3,...,2^{19}$. If you want *proper* divisors, use $2^{21}$
Using a comment by Nicolas:

$ 1.2.2^2........2^{19}  \rightarrow  1.2.3.2^2..2^18 \rightarrow 1.2.3.5.2^2....2^{17} \rightarrow  1.2.3.5.7.2^2.....2^{16} \rightarrow 1.2.3^2.5.7.2^2.....2^{15} \rightarrow 1.2.3^{10}.5.7.2^2.2^3.....2^8 \rightarrow ....$

Comment: $2^{20}$ has *$21$* divisors total, $20$ proper divisors.

Comment: There are several smaller  than $2^{19}$.

Comment: Ah, right , I can substitute a large power by a prime,

Comment: Thanks for giving me the time to edit,I appreciate it!.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't understand this solution. What are those arrows?

Comment: @galf: the idea is that I can substitute the high power of 2 with a power of $3$, so that, in the first $\rightarrow$, I get rid of $2^{20}$ by substituting it with the much smaller $3$. Then I do something similar with $2^{19}$ , substituting it by $3^2$, and so on. But you reach a point where $3^n > 3^m $ and then you have to change your approach a bit.

Comment: What will one get at the end of this procedure? Would all higher powers of two get converted to powers of 3?

Comment: @Galf, you need to consider the case of having $3^n >2^m$, but other than that, yes.

Comment: But wouldn't the number be much greater than 240?

Comment: @Galf: no, the idea is to collect copies of $2^n$ and substitute $2^2$ by $3$ as many times as possible.

Comment: Can you take an example of n=4 and explain your method by adding it to your answer? It looks interesting.

Comment: @Galf: sure, please give me some time, I am on it.

Comment: Sure. I shall wait :) And I am sure people will like your answer after you edit it.

Comment: @Galf: I need to be gone for a while, I will come back later if you are interested.

Comment: Yes. Edit your answer and then ping me here in the comments. :)